# If a (US-based) website repeatedly allows users to post my copyrighted material what legal actions can I take?

Tags: united-states, copyright, california, online-piracy

I'm a university lecturer in Australia teaching mathematics.  I produce question sheets for my students.  It takes significant effort to produce high-quality questions.  These question sheets are protected under copyright law.  A **US-based website** allows students to post these sheets and pay for someone else to provide solutions which are then uploaded back to the website.  The website appears to be based in **California.**

They provide a mechanism to take the sheets down by filing a copyright complaint.  It can take a long time to be processed, by which time an answer can be uploaded and the cheating student sometimes gets a terrible solution, but sometimes gets a good solution.  Once they have taken this down, the sheet is often re-uploaded.

In my current iteration, we are dealing with the 3rd round of takedown requests for the same material.  It takes longer to make a decision about whether to take it down than it seems to take for the student(s) to reupload the questions afterwards.

What legal options do I have if this happens repeatedly?  This company definitely has the technical sophistication required to ensure that material that has previously been taken down for copyright infringement cannot be reuploaded,

Comment: [DMCA takedown](https://giga.law/blog/2016/07/13/5-myths-about-dmca-take-down-notices). Each singe time. The act says they have to take the stuff down as soon as possible, which in practice depends on the provider: sometimes below 24 hours, most often below 3 days.

Comment: There is a [repeat infringer](https://www.mediainstitute.org/2011/07/12/the-dmca-and-repeat-infringers/) clause in the DMCA, but that probably would only apply if the same student is uploading copyrighted material repeatedly.

Comment: I suspect it is the same student (first time they got Q 1-5 answered, this time they are asking for Q 6-9), but they won't provide me with the information on who is doing it.

Comment: Easy way to find out would be to place some sort of unique mark on that student's (or a different one on each student's) sheet. Of course make it so it's only recognizable to you.

Comment: 150 students...  and the online system we have would require me to upload each individually.  I did that for their final exam last semester, but that was a huge amount of work.

Comment: @random_downvoter - I recognize I'm new to this particular site, but if I'm asking something out of the scope (or there's something else wrong with my question), I won't learn the standards at law.stackexchange.com from a downvote without an 
explanation.

Comment: The relevant law here is the [Online Copyright Infringement Liability Limitation Act (OCILLA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Copyright_Infringement_Liability_Limitation_Act), which you may like to read about.

Comment: @Joel Some users here take an absurdly formalist approach to Law.SE's rule against asking for legal advice. Anyone who asks a question about anything that has actually happened to them can safely expect to get at least one knee-jerk downvote or vote to close the question.

Comment: Suppose two students uploaded the same material to the site.  Would the site supply the same solutions to both students?  If so, and if *you* were the second "student" (perhaps pseudonymously), you would be able to identify the guilty party fairly easily.  I would also wonder whether it would be possible to get a subpoena requiring the site to reveal the student by filing an action against the student, who is probably also violating copyright by distributing the material.

Comment: This site allows pays people (mostly in foreign countries) to answer questions.  I can actually see the solutions (by buying a $15/month subscription).  Sometimes the solution is unremarkable enough that people could innocently have similar solutions.  Sometimes it's obvious.  In my current situation, we're in our 4th round of DMCA take down requests for uploading the same thing.